# Delete zero sized files from a specified folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file

How to Delete zero sized files from a specified folder using batch file.
I am able to remove from current directory with following command
FOR %F IN (*.*) DO (IF %~zF LSS 1 DEL %F)

but I want to remove from child folder i.e.
I have following structure core/logs/. My batch file is in core and I want to delete 0 sized files from core/logs/  directory.
I tried following command but it did not worked

FOR %F IN (logs/) DO (IF %~zF LSS 1 DEL %F)

Comment: You must be using `for %F in (*)` to delete from the current directory, not `for %F in (.)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your current directory is the location of the batch file:

```
for %F in (logs\*) do if %~zF equ 0 del "%F"
```

If the current directory could be anywhere, then `%~dp0` yields the path to the executing batch script:

```
for %F in ("%~dp0logs\*") do if %~zF equ 0 del "%F"
```

---

Here is the original answer when I thought OP wanted to deltete from the entire tree:

This will delete all 0 length files in the entire tree rooted at the current directory.

```
for /r %F in (*) do if %~zF equ 0 del "%F"
```

You can specify a different root by providing a root path after the /R option

```
for /r "c:\myRoot\" %F in (*) do if %~zF equ 0 del "%F"
```

Comment: This will recursively go inside all folder under core/, I want to delete files under only core/logs/

Comment: how can I do with relative path because on different machine absolute path can change but my folder structure would be same.